# Do I need to protect 12/2 cable while running them through finished walls? Onto concrete foundation?

Tags: wiring

I'd like to run three new 12/2 cables for 20A circuits into my attached garage. Was wondering if I need to shield it at all if it's inside a finished wall or ceiling.

Circuit 1 will stay inside the finished wall and be broken into a 20A GFCI and normal 20A outlet (on the "load line" side of the GFCI outlet). The cables for circuits 2 and 3 will go into one side of the finished wall and be broken out in a metal junction box on the opposite side (inside the garage). From there, I think I will need to run 12/2 Metal Clad along the concrete foundation to a metal-encased 20A GFCI outlet, since it's in the open and exposed to damage/water (the foundation isn't leaking but you never know).

I live in Massachusetts. This is my first home DIY electrical project but I'm comfortable working around electricity.

Comment: EMT is probably a better choice than MC for running along your foundation.

Comment: So I take it this is an attached garage. With that you can run the Romex inside the walls through bored holes that need to be 1-1/4” back from the face of the studs if the edge of the hole is at least 1-1/4” back no protection other than the 1/2” Sheetrock is needed. The wire can also be run in the ceiling. I am not sure why you would want to run the cable exposed that is not clear MC will usually pass but a picky inspector can fail it when exposed in an area that it can be damaged. You will need GFCI protection for all receptacles inside the garage and In-use or extreme duty covers outside.

Comment: @EdBeal Yes, it's an attached garage and I will need to run wires in the ceiling of the garage for the lights. Kind of a dumb question but I feel I need to ask since I've never done it before: I'd need to cut out the finished drywall to drill holes in the studs and then repair it right? I've seen a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HME5amrYG5A) video on how to do it and it doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: `I am not sure why you would want to run the cable exposed`. Circuit 2 & 3 include GFCI outlets mounted to concrete foundation. I'm considering @Ecnerwal's suggestion but a little put off that it requires a special tool to bend EMT, which is why I'm considering Metal Clad.

Comment: [Another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Stx8wm8qQvY) shows that MC was used where it's out of reach. I'm going to use MC for running it along the ceiling and follow Ecnerwal's advice and use EMT for Circuit 2 & 3 where they come down from the ceiling into outlets.

Comment: You don’t have to use a bender you can purchase 90’s  or conduit body’s that make the bends in emt.  You can run Romex on the ceiling exposed above 8’ but if it’s finished my opinion would be MC would look better. If you use MC make sure to use the insulating bushings that normally come with a spool inspectors look for them the red is easy to spot. Cutting a strip out boring holes and covering back up is quick, there are long drill bits that can reduce the holes but for a single job cut the strips.

Comment: All your garage outlets will need to be GFCI protected whether your foundation is currently leaking or not. It's not an option on newer versions of NEC, and MA is probably on a new enough version to require it. Even if they're not, it's worth doing anyway since NEC is the _minimum_ safety required.